# Can someone please explain these two simple loops?

Tags: java

Hello I have a problem with understanding the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vstup = "DEN DOBRY";
    String vystup = "";
    int i = 2;
    do {
        vystup = vystup + vstup.charAt(i);
        i++;
    } while (vystup.charAt(0)>=vstup.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(vystup);
}
```

Why does this one print out "N D"?

And the second one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vstup = "Mama má emu.";
    String vystup = "";
    for (int i = 0;i<vstup.length();i++)
        if ((i % 3) == 1) vystup = vystup.concat(vstup.substring(i, i+2));
        System.out.println(vystup);
}
```

Why does this one print out "am m eu."?

Comment: These pieces of code are simple enough that you should be able to simulate the program execution with a pencil and paper. Perhaps that will reveal to you how the logic is working.

Comment: What do *you* expect the code to print out?

Comment: Well I just dont understand what does "while (vystup.charAt(0)>=vstup.charAt(i));" mean and in the second one i just dont understand why it writes those letters, vystup changes only when i%3=1 so it should be " m e ." no? Because for example 4%3 is 1 or am i not understanding this correctly?

Comment: for 2nd one, It does a `substring(i, i+2)`, so takes 2 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues

1. The first part of the code can throw index out of bounds exception(or similar)
2. The second part of the code can also throw similar exception

Example Input for 1st case: ZYXWV

```java
    do {
        vystup = vystup + vstup.charAt(i);
        i++;
    } while (vystup.charAt(0) >= vstup.charAt(i)); // i can get invalid
```

Example Input for 2nd case: ab

```java
  if ((i % 3) == 1) vystup = vystup.concat(vstup.substring(i, i+2)); // i + 2 can be invalid index
```

### What 1st does?

1. Starts from 2nd index `i = 2`
2. concatenates character at index to output and increments index by 1
3. repeat step 2 if character at current (incremented) index is lesser than or equal to the first character(`0`th index) of the string
4. By `>=`, it compares the code points (numeric values of the character)

### What 2nd does?

1. Starting from 2nd character(`1` index), selects 2 adjacent characters(2 and 3rd character)
2. repeat by moving 3 character (from 2nd character exclusive) to right

```
str:     M    a    m    a          m    á          e    m    u    .
index:   0    1    2    3     4    5    6     7    8    9   10    11  

i%3==1        i   i+1         i   i+1         i   i+1       i    i+1
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, i still have no idea XD

Comment: Why are those indexes "lesser" then the others

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but i still dont get it the first one i have a vague idea now but the second i dont get why it writes those letters, vystup changes only when i%3=1 so it should be " m eu." no? Because for example 4%3 is 1

Comment: oh no sorry, i am just dumb, sorry thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Glad to have helped you. With focus and time, surely we can understand even complex topics. There are many mediums to learn. Use it to your advantage and do awesome things. Have a happy time :)